# Can you live link a youtube video in Keynote as opposed to embedding an offline copy?

Tags: keynote, youtube

Powerpoint allows to [stream a video](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-or-link-to-a-video-on-youtube-8340ec69-4cee-4fe1-ab96-4849154bc6db) directly as part of a presentation:

> In PowerPoint, you can insert or link to an online video, and then play it during your presentation.
>
> The video plays directly from the website, and it has the site's controls for playing, pausing, volume, and so on. The PowerPoint playback features (Fade, Bookmark, Trim, and so on) don't apply to online videos.
>
> Because the video is stored on a web site, rather than in your presentation, you must be connected to the internet in order for the video to play successfully.

I was wondering whether it is possible to stream a Youtube video from a Keynote slide directly, (using the video URL?), without having to download the .mp4 file on the computer.

So how can I include an online video directly into a Keynote presentation?

Comment: Comments shouldn’t be used to express appreciation, or speculation about intentions of other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, keynote is cross platform (web, iOS and macos) and designed to not live-link to YouTube.

Use another app. One to try us [LiveSlides](https://www.liveslides.com/).

Consider that you will still need internet connection to play the video because it is still linking to the website where the video is, if you do not download it, means that you might be in a situation where the presentation will not work.

Comment: has anybody experience with osx Catalina and LiveSlides - mine seem to be broken after the os update

Answer (score 1):

Keynote 8.2 still does not support embedding Videos from a URL. 
However, there are plenty of websites and apps that can download a YouTube video.

Also, if you open a YouTube video in VLC, then click on that tiny playlist icon, there should be the option "Properties" (or something like that) if you right-click on the video.
The original source should be shown in the up coming window.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible idea. Embedding just the URL just adds another point of failure.

If your goal is *to hold a presentation* then you download the video and embed the whole video.

Other options, hacks and workarounds are not conducive to reliable presentations.

Make the keynote file self-contained.

That means *functional* even if the URL changes, you are offline, the source changes the availability, the owner deletes it, you have to hold your presentation where censorship is a bit more prevalent than where you compose it [buffering…]